# checking error while using fadeout and fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<div class="pro_avatars model-shadow">
  <div class="unclickable"></div>
  //code
</div>

<div class="pro_crop model-shadow">
  //code
</div>
```

Above it the html code.
and below is the js code

```js
cancel.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  un.hide();
  preview.fadeOut('fast');
  input.val('');
});

form.on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
              url: '../ajaxify/ajax_requests/change_avatar.php',
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              dataType: "json",
              method: "POST",
              data: new FormData(this),
              success: function(data) {

                  var img_name = data.name;
                  $('.pro_avatars').fadeOut('fast');
                  $('.overlay').show();
                  blur.addBlur();
                  $('.pro_crop_img > img').attr('src', '../temp/resized/Resized_' + img_name);
                  cropper.fadeIn('fast');
                  if ($('.pro_crop_img > img').width() < 400) {
                    var hmm = $('.pro_crop_img > img').css('width');
                    $('.pro_crop_img').css('width', hmm + "px");
                  }
```

when i press the submit button , the crop div has to overlay the avatar div but am getting issues doing it.

and am not sure where the problem is .
need some help, and thanks for your help

Comment: Man try to check all the syntax of the code, meaning i think you mistake or missing some closing brackets. Like at the `form.on` line you open the function but i don't see any closing one

Comment: @GiorgioG its just a snippet, i have only shared the part that has to do the fadeout and fadein of the div elements